# Quartz cron expression to execute every 5weeks(35 days)

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to figure out the cron expression for executing once in 5weeks, that is 35 days from a particular day. I couldnt find a solution directly using quartz.

[LINK HERE](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html)

Can someone advise?

Comment: What do you mean "from a particular day"? Could you give some examples?

Comment: Can you check this  0 0 12 1/35 * ? *
You can generate your cron using http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: let it be from 1st of a month

Comment: but 1/35 will execute every month.. U can see that in the cron schedule in the same site

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution for this.

Following solution will help you:

Create a job in quartz with below cron, make *_JOB_DETAILS table job_data column data as milliseconds of next fire time.

```
It will run every week(You can make this every day also). 
0 0 12 ? * MON *
```

Quartz job will call java application for every Week(Monday 12:00 AM). On your business logic check job_data with current time. If it exceeds execute your logic else do nothing. After executing of your logic update the JOB_DATA with below time, then next trigger time will store in job_data.

```
Calendar c=new GregorianCalendar();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 35);
c.getTime();//add this data
```

You will get expected result.

Comment: This will be on every month not every 35days.

Answer (score 0):

Pointless to write such expression (it won't work), Try to use http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html rather than cron expression which is just not suitable for this type of job.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Puchacz, cron expressions are not suited for these types of schedules. You should use CalendarIntervalTrigger with the week repeat interval unit and 5 for the repeat interval. Code-wise there is hardly any difference between using cron and calendar interval triggers in Quartz.

See below for an example schedule of a CalendarIntervalTrigger that starts firing at midnight, November 1st, 2017. By changing the start time you can adjust the time of day when you want your job to be fired.

[image: [Sample CalendarIntervalTrigger]

Comment: You have some links for sample programs based on that?

Comment: Why do not you use Google and search for CalendarIntervalTrigger sample or example.The second link (https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.quartz.CalendarIntervalTrigger) is usable.

Comment: Thank you! But I was not able to related the way this code is written.